# Powering multiple loads at same voltage with separated DC-DC converters

Tags: power-supply, switches, dc-dc-converter

I'm working on the power distribution PCB of a battery powered robot with multiple loads at 24V, 12V and 5V. My idea is to use a big 24V converter, and then another two smaller converters to go from 24 to 12 and 5V. This PCB needs to be able to cut power to different groups of loads independently, so I was going to use power switch ICs or MOSFETs and drivers.

My problem is, that while looking for the components I realized that, for example, I only have two groups of 12V loads and the 12V converter is cheap and small enough that I could just put two of them, each of them powering a group independently, and use their on-off control input instead of adding two switches.

I think this idea can work, but I've been searching for similar implementations on the internet and found nothing. Is this a bad idea? Are there any disadvantages to using multiple regulators instead of one followed by switches that I´m not taking into account, apart from the increase in price?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a bad idea?

It's fine.

It offers redundancy: if one of the 12V loads shorts out, the buck converter will go into a current limit mode, saving the main supply. So it's like using a smart protected load switch.

If you have substantial decoupling capacitance on your 12V loads, and you want to turn one of them on and off without affecting the others, a buck converter will do this easily. On the other hand, a switch sitting between a +12V supply and a bunch of discharged capacitors will have to turn on slowly and limit current, which means the internal MOSFET needs to operate in linear mode and dissipate power. Depending on the amount of capacitance this may get a bit complicated if the MOSFET is external to the switch, with the IC not being able to sense its temperature and protect it.

Also, conduction losses are RI² so two identical buck converters carrying half the current each will have lower conduction losses if you use the same chips.

Comment: Thank you and @frr for your help. You give me the reassurance I needed to follow with my work. But I still wonder, why didn't I found any examples of this aproach online.? Is it just not a common requirement to indepently control the power supply of different loads?

Answer (score 2):

Au contraire, mon ami! :-) This is actually a pretty bright idea, in general.

You don't mention what sorts of loads you have there, at +5 and +12 Volts. If they are motors, you might as well switch them or PWM them directly (specific protection would be needed against inductive spikes and EMI) - but if those loads are just power rails for digital electronics, and each rail would be filtered by large capacitors *after* the FET switch, I strongly suggest that you instead just use the "enable" input of your buck converters - it is your low hanging fruit / direct approach to a neatly defined soft-start.

BTW you may want to keep the digital circuitry in RESET state during the soft power-up, to prevent erratic effects / undesired operation on power-up.

I have my own [example](http://frr.g6.cz/htpc/atx_3x_buck.pdf) on how to soft-start capacitive loads, preventing the hard-switched inrush. It's an ATX-ish PSU, making 3.3V and 5V and +5VSB from 12V input, while also switching 12V in a "soft" fashion (using a FET slowed down by negative local feedback).

If you're going to use cheap buck modules from the far east (on a PCB, 1-5 USD a piece), think twice about how much load you can subject them to, and maybe add some final touches. Such as, these buck modules tend to be sync-recfified, which is perfect, but they have a polarity-reversal-protection diode on the input, which will produce heat (you can just replace that with a wire bridge), they typically have pretty cheap elyt capacitors, which beg to be replaced with solid polymer immediately, etc. Cooling tends to be ignored on these modules - test them under your desired level of load and if it doesn't look good, either use more of those buck modules, or try to thermocouple a heatsink to them. I know people who went on to design their own PCB's, improving upon the cheap off-the-shelf design.